# Parsing options from selection

Tags: python, selenium, request

I am trying to get the following:

```
<select name="Detect" id="313" class="select" style="display: none;">
<option value="650" maxmad="15" maxpad="2" status="TRUE" context="24"> 5 </option>

<option value="660" maxmad="16" maxpad="2" status="TRUE" context="25"> 6 </option>
```

I want to scrape and print out the following, the 650 from "value", and the 15 from "maxmad" and print it like this (There is a lot of these options, and I want to print all of them):

```
650: 15
660: 16
670: 17
etc
etc
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
window = driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
site = driver.get("www.website.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "html.parser")
for option in soup.find_all("option"):
    print('id: {}, maxmad: {}'.format(option['id'], option.text))
```

Comment: Where is the 314 in the output coming from. There is only one `id` and that is 313

Comment: I added it just to show what I wanted, but there are multiple options, I just pasted one of them, the rest look identical other than different ids and maxmads

Comment: Are there multiple just multiple options, or also multiple selects (that give you the `id`

Comment: Hey, I can see it was confusing and I apologize, I just edited my post and added the second option, they continue for about 10 more options, each time the value increments by 10 and the maxmad increments by 1.

Comment: But you are not using value at all, or do you want that instead of `id`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, really tired! I want the value instead of id so like this: 
value : 650, maxmad:5
value : 660, maxmad:6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple errors here that are more difficult to find and try out because you download the page every time. You should first make a minimal HTML file that has the relevant code and then use that to test the parsing code.

Then the first thing you'll notice that you use `site.find_all` where you should use `soup.find_all`. After fixing that you'll find that `option` has no `id`, and that you should search for `select` to get the `id`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = """
<html>
<body>
<select name="Detect" id="313" class="select" style="display: none;">
<option value="650" maxmad="15" maxpad="2" status="TRUE" context="24"> 5 </option>
<option value="660" maxmad="16" maxpad="2" status="TRUE" context="25"> 6 </option>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, "html.parser")
select = soup.select("select")[0]
for select in soup.select("select"):
    ident = select['id']
    for option in select.find_all("option"):
        print('value: {}, maxmad: {}'.format(option['value'], option['maxmad'])
```

which gives:

```
value: 650, maxmad:  15 
value: 660, maxmad:  16
```

Comment: Instead of html_str, how would I use a website there instead? also there are multiple options, I just pasted one, so how would i print all of them?

Comment: if `driver.get("www.website.com")` gives you the html then just put those first 3 lines back in place and replace `html_str` with `site`.

Comment: @KingPey I update the answer. Very confusing that you print maxmad not with the value of the attribute maxmad but with the associated text.

Comment: No I want the attribute, I want it to print:
value: 650, maxmad: 15
value:660, maxmad:16

like that...

Comment: Last update from my side. I also changed `id` to `value`

Comment: I think I need to post the full HTML, my mistake. I realize its confusing.